# How to efficiently generate large, uniformly distributed, random integers in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have been wondering what would be the best way to get *good* randomness in bash, i.e., what would be a procedure to get a random positive integer between `MIN` and `MAX` such that

1. The range can be arbitrarily large (or at least, say, up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1);
2. Values are uniformly distributed (i.e., no bias);
3. It is efficient.

An efficient way to get randomness in bash is to use the `$RANDOM` variable. However, this only samples a value between 0 and 2<sup>15</sup>-1, which may not be large enough for all purposes. People typically use a modulo to get it into the range they want, e.g.,

```
MIN=0
MAX=12345
rnd=$(( $RANDOM % ($MAX + 1 - $MIN) + $MIN ))
```

This, additionally, creates a bias unless `$MAX` happens to divide 2<sup>15</sup>-1=32767. E.g., if `$MIN` is 0 and `$MAX` is 9, then the values 0 through 7 are slightly more probable than the values 8 and 9, as `$RANDOM` will never be 32768 or 32769. This bias gets worse as the range increases, e.g., if `$MIN` is 0 and `$MAX` is 9999, then the numbers 0 through 2767 have a probability of <sup>4</sup>/<sub>32767</sub>, while the numbers 2768 through 9999 only have a probability of <sup>3</sup>/<sub>32767</sub>.

So while the above method fulfills condition 3, it does not fulfill conditions 1 and 2.

The best method that I came up with so far in trying to satisfy conditions 1 and 2 was to use `/dev/urandom` as follows:

```
MIN=0
MAX=1234567890
while
  rnd=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 0-9 | fold -w${#MAX} | head -1 | sed 's/^0*//;')
  [ -z $rnd ] && rnd=0
  (( $rnd < $MIN || $rnd > $MAX ))
do :
done
```

Basically, just collect randomness from `/dev/urandom` (might consider to use `/dev/random` instead if a cryptographically strong pseudorandom number generator is desired, and if you have *lots* of time, or else maybe a hardware random number generator), delete every character that's not a decimal digit, fold the output to the length of `$MAX` and cut leading 0's. If we happened to only get 0's then `$rnd` is empty, so in this case set `rnd` to `0`. Check if the result is outside our range and if so, then repeat. I forced the "body" of the while loop into the guard here so as to force execution of the body at least once, in the spirit of emulating a `do ... while` loop, since `rnd` is undefined to start with.

I think I fulfilled conditions 1 and 2 here, but now I screwed up condition 3. It's kinda slow. Takes up to a second or so (tenth of a second when I'm lucky). Actually, the loop is not even guaranteed to terminate (although the probability of termination converges to 1 as time increases).

Is there an efficient way to get unbiased random integers, within a pre-specified and potentially large range, in bash? (I'll continue to investigate when time allows, but in the meantime I thought someone here might have a cool idea!)

## Table of Answers

1. The most basic (and hence portable) idea is to generate a random bitstring just long enough. There are different ways of generating a random bitstring, either using bash's built-in `$RANDOM` variable or using `od` and `/dev/urandom` (or `/dev/random`). If the random number is greater than `$MAX`, start over.

   - [Complete bash solution for arbitrary ranges using either `$RANDOM` or `/dev/urandom`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157837)
   - [The general idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157274)
   - [Get random bitstring using either `openssl` or `od` with `/dev/urandom`. Beautify with `tr`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157266)
   - [Get random bitstring using `od` with `/dev/random`. Beautify with `awk`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157263)
2. Alternatively, it is possible to use external tools.

   - [The Perl solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157259)

     - Pro: quite portable, simple, flexible
     - Contra: not for very large numbers above 2<sup>32</sup>-1
   - [The Python solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157321)

     - Pro: simple, flexible, works even for large numbers
     - Contra: less portable
   - [The zsh solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157267)

     - Pro: good for people who use zsh anyway
     - Contra: probably even less portable

Comment: Why pick out only integers, instead of base64-encoding the random bits, then converting a certain number of characters (depending on the range needed) from the encoded form to base10 from base64?

Comment: Does it _need_ to be bash? Would something like `rand=$(command)` do if `command` returns an iteger that fulfills your requirements?

Comment: @muru It's a nice idea actually. I had spent some thought on a similar idea, using `dd if=/dev/urandom 2>/dev/null` and piping that through `od -t d` (avoids the detour through base64), but it's not clear to me how the conversion happens and whether it is indeed unbiased. If you can expand your idea to an efficient, working script and explain why there's no bias, it would make for a great answer. :)

Comment: @terdon I would prefer bash. I mean, of course you can invoke `python` or `perl` or your favorite language, but this is not available everywhere. I'd prefer something more portable. Well, `awk`'s random function would be fine, I guess. But the more portable, the better :)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along the lines of `perl -e 'print int(rand(2**32-1))');`. That is pretty darn portable and will be very fast. Awk won't cut it since most implementations start from the same seed. So you get the same random number on subsequent runs. It only changes within the same run.

Comment: @terdon I will upvote if you post that as an answer, but I'd wait a bit before accepting it in the hope someone will find a more bash'ier solution. Of course `perl` isn't that far-fetched, but it's not available by default on a "typical" Linux installation (whatever that means). What about using bash's `$RANDOM` variable as a seed for `awk`?

Comment: Actually, it is available by default on a "typical" Linux. The only systems I've heard of that don't have it are certain UNICEs and embedded Linuxen. Also, [apparently](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123149/22222) minimal installs of slackware but again, not a typical Linux in any way.

Comment: @terdon I honestly didn't know that it is available by default on most typical Linuxes - good to know! But still, it's not POSIX. It's not available by default on FreeBSD or NetBSD, which aren't that uncommon. Nor is Busybox (granted, my above examples are bash and not ash - but that can be easily fixed. `$RANDOM`, [`tr`, `fold`, `head`, `sed` and `awk` are all available](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#commands)). Thanks for your answer, I do think it is a fine solution, it will work on most Linuxes and is simple, fast, reliable, flexible and fulfills all my conditions. :)

Comment: I added a table of answers to organize my mind ;) All answers are good, they each have their pros and cons, and together they give a big picture. I'm also currently looking at yet another possibility to generate a large random bitstring using bash's builtin `$RANDOM` and bitwise operations, as proposed by @EliahKagan in a comment [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525599/how-to-display-a-random-line-from-a-text-file/525624#comment719930_525624).

Comment: Using `$[]` for math is deprecated. It is preferred to use `$(())`.

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat the `$(())` nested within the outer set since the arithmetic context has already been created. I'm sorry I didn't point that out in my earlier message.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Makes sense. Done :)

Comment: Python solution is also slowest, it takes 0.05 - 0.07 seconds to load python. Imagine generating a random number in a loop...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you all for all your great answers. I ended up with the following solution, that I would like to share.

Before I go into any more detail about the whys and hows, here's the ***tl;dr***: my shiny new script :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Generates a random integer in a given range

# computes the ceiling of log2
# i.e., for parameter x returns the lowest integer l such that 2**l >= x
log2() {
  local x=$1 n=1 l=0
  while (( x>n && n>0 ))
  do
    let n*=2 l++
  done
  echo $l
}

# uses $RANDOM to generate an n-bit random bitstring uniformly at random
#  (if we assume $RANDOM is uniformly distributed)
# takes the length n of the bitstring as parameter, n can be up to 60 bits
get_n_rand_bits() {
  local n=$1 rnd=$RANDOM rnd_bitlen=15
  while (( rnd_bitlen < n ))
  do
    rnd=$(( rnd<<15|$RANDOM ))
    let rnd_bitlen+=15
  done
  echo $(( rnd>>(rnd_bitlen-n) ))
}

# alternative implementation of get_n_rand_bits:
# uses /dev/urandom to generate an n-bit random bitstring uniformly at random
#  (if we assume /dev/urandom is uniformly distributed)
# takes the length n of the bitstring as parameter, n can be up to 56 bits
get_n_rand_bits_alt() {
  local n=$1
  local nb_bytes=$(( (n+7)/8 ))
  local rnd=$(od --read-bytes=$nb_bytes --address-radix=n --format=uL /dev/urandom | tr --delete " ")
  echo $(( rnd>>(nb_bytes*8-n) ))
}

# for parameter max, generates an integer in the range {0..max} uniformly at random
# max can be an arbitrary integer, needs not be a power of 2
rand() {
  local rnd max=$1
  # get number of bits needed to represent $max
  local bitlen=$(log2 $((max+1)))
  while
    # could use get_n_rand_bits_alt instead if /dev/urandom is preferred over $RANDOM
    rnd=$(get_n_rand_bits $bitlen)
    (( rnd > max ))
  do :
  done
  echo $rnd
}

# MAIN SCRIPT

# check number of parameters
if (( $# != 1 && $# != 2 ))
then
  cat <<EOF 1>&2
Usage: $(basename $0) [min] max

Returns an integer distributed uniformly at random in the range {min..max}
min defaults to 0
(max - min) can be up to 2**60-1  
EOF
  exit 1
fi

# If we have one parameter, set min to 0 and max to $1
# If we have two parameters, set min to $1 and max to $2
max=0
while (( $# > 0 ))
do
  min=$max
  max=$1
  shift
done

# ensure that min <= max
if (( min > max ))
then
  echo "$(basename $0): error: min is greater than max" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

# need absolute value of diff since min (and also max) may be negative
diff=$((max-min)) && diff=${diff#-}

echo $(( $(rand $diff) + min ))
```

Save that to `~/bin/rand` and you have at your availability a sweet random function in bash that can sample an integer in a given arbitrary range. The range may contain negative and positive integers and can be up to 2<sup>60</sup>-1 in length:

```
$ rand 
Usage: rand [min] max

Returns an integer distributed uniformly at random in the range {min..max}
min defaults to 0
(max - min) can be up to 2**60-1  
$ rand 1 10
9
$ rand -43543 -124
-15757
$ rand -3 3
1
$ for i in {0..9}; do rand $((2**60-1)); done
777148045699177620
456074454250332606
95080022501817128
993412753202315192
527158971491831964
336543936737015986
1034537273675883580
127413814010621078
758532158881427336
924637728863691573
```

All ideas by the other answerers were great. The answers by [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157259), [J.F. Sebastian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157321), and [jimmij](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157267) used external tools to do the task in a simple and efficient manner. However, I preferred a true bash solution for maximum portability, and maybe a little bit, simply out of love for bash ;)

[Ramesh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157266)'s and [l0b0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157263)'s answers used `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` in combination with `od`. That's good, however, their approaches had the disadvantage of only being able to sample random integers in the range 0 to 2<sup>8n</sup>-1 for some n, since this method samples bytes, i.e., bitstrings of length 8. These are quite big jumps with increasing n.

Finally, [Falco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157274)'s answer describes the general idea how this could be done for *arbitrary* ranges (not only powers of two). Basically, for a given range `{0..max}`, we can determine what the next power of two is, i.e., exactly how many *bits* are required to represent `max` as a bitstring. Then we can sample just that many bits and see whether this bistring, as an integer, is greater than `max`. If so, repeat. Since we sample just as many bits as are required to represent `max`, each iteration has a probability greater or equal than 50% of succeeding (50% in the worst case, 100% in the best case). So this is very efficient.

My script is basically a concrete implementation of Falco's answer, written in pure bash and highly efficient since it uses bash's built-in bitwise operations to sample bitstrings of the desired length. It additionally honors an idea by [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525599/how-to-display-a-random-line-from-a-text-file/525624#comment719930_525624) that suggests to use the built-in `$RANDOM` variable by concatening bitstrings resulting from repeated invocations of `$RANDOM`. I actually implemented both the possibilities to use `/dev/urandom` and `$RANDOM`. By default the above script uses `$RANDOM`. (And ok, if using `/dev/urandom` we need [od](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html) and [tr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), but these are backed by POSIX.)

## So how does it work?

Before I get into this, two observations:

1. It turns out bash can't handle integers larger than 2<sup>63</sup>-1. See for yourself:

   ```
   $ echo $((2**63-1))
   9223372036854775807
   $ echo $((2**63))
   -9223372036854775808
   ```

   It would appear that bash internally uses signed 64-bit integers to store integers. So, at 2<sup>63</sup> it "wraps around" and we get a negative integer. So we can't hope to get any range larger than 2<sup>63</sup>-1 with whatever random function we use. Bash simply can't handle it.
2. Whenever we want to sample a value in an arbitrary range between `min` and `max` with possibly `min != 0`, we can simply sample a value between `0` and `max-min` instead and then add `min` to the final result. This works even if `min` and possibly also `max` are *negative*, but we need to be careful to sample a value between `0` and *the absolute value of* `max-min`. So then, we can focus on how to sample a random value between `0` and an arbitrary positive integer `max`. The rest is easy.

**Step 1: Determine how many bits are needed to represent an integer (the logarithm)**

So for a given value `max`, we want to know just how many bits are needed to represent it as a bitstring. This is so that later we can randomly sample only just as many bits as are needed, which makes the script so efficient.

Let's see. Since with `n` bits, we can represent up to the value 2<sup>n</sup>-1, then the number `n` of bits needed to represent an arbitrary value `x` is ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>(x+1)). So, we need a function to compute the ceiling of a logarithm to the base 2. It is rather self-explanatory:

```
log2() {
  local x=$1 n=1 l=0
  while (( x>n && n>0 ))
  do
    let n*=2 l++
  done
  echo $l
}
```

We need the condition `n>0` so if it grows too great, wraps around and becomes negative, the loop is guaranteed to terminate.

**Step 2: Sample a random a bitstring of length `n`**

The most portable ideas are to either use `/dev/urandom` (or even `/dev/random` if there is a strong reason) or bash's built-in `$RANDOM` variable. Let's look at how to do it with `$RANDOM` first.

*Option A: Using `$RANDOM`*

This uses the [idea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525599/how-to-display-a-random-line-from-a-text-file/525624#comment719930_525624) mentioned by Eliah Kagan. Basically, since `$RANDOM` samples a 15-bit integer, we can use `$((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM))` to sample a 30-bit integer. That means, shift a first invocation of `$RANDOM` by 15 bits to the left, and apply a bitwise or with a second invocation of `$RANDOM`, effectively concatening two independently sampled bitstrings (or at least as independent as bash's built-in `$RANDOM` goes).

We can repeat this to obtain a 45-bit or 60-bit integer. After that bash can't handle it anymore, but this means we can easily sample a random value between 0 and 2<sup>60</sup>-1. So, to sample an n-bit integer, we repeat the procedure until our random bitstring, whose length grows in 15-bit steps, has a length greater or equal than n. Finally, we cut off the bits that are too much by appropriately bitwise shifting to the right, and we end up with a n-bit random integer.

```
get_n_rand_bits() {
  local n=$1 rnd=$RANDOM rnd_bitlen=15
  while (( rnd_bitlen < n ))
  do
    rnd=$(( rnd<<15|$RANDOM ))
    let rnd_bitlen+=15
  done
  echo $(( rnd>>(rnd_bitlen-n) ))
}
```

*Option B: Using `/dev/urandom`*

Alternatively, we can use `od` and `/dev/urandom` to sample an n-bit integer. `od` will read bytes, i.e., bitstrings of length 8. Similarly as in the previous method, we sample just so many bytes that the equivalent number of sampled *bits* is greater or equal than n, and cut off the bits that are too much.

The lowest number of bytes needed to get at least n bits is the lowest multiple of 8 that is greater or equal than n, i.e., floor((n+7)/8).

This only works up to 56-bit integers. Sampling one more byte would get us an 64-bit integer, i.e., a value up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1, which bash can't handle.

```
get_n_rand_bits_alt() {
  local n=$1
  local nb_bytes=$(( (n+7)/8 ))
  local rnd=$(od --read-bytes=$nb_bytes --address-radix=n --format=uL /dev/urandom | tr --delete " ")
  echo $(( rnd>>(nb_bytes*8-n) ))
}
```

**Putting the pieces together: Get random integers in *arbitrary* ranges**

We can sample `n`-bit bitstrings now, but we want to sample integers in a range from `0` to `max`, *uniformly at random*, where `max` may be arbitrary, not necessarily a power of two. (We can't use modulo as that creates a bias.)

The whole point why we tried so hard to sample just as many bits as are needed to represent the value `max`, is that we can now safely (and efficiently) use a loop to repeatedly sample an `n`-bit bitstring until we sample a value that is lower or equal to `max`. In the worst case (`max` is a power of two), each iteration terminates with a probability of 50%, and in the best case (`max` is a power of two minus one), the first iteration terminates with certainty.

```
rand() {
  local rnd max=$1
  # get number of bits needed to represent $max
  local bitlen=$(log2 $((max+1)))
  while
    # could use get_n_rand_bits_alt instead if /dev/urandom is preferred over $RANDOM
    rnd=$(get_n_rand_bits $bitlen)
    (( rnd > max ))
  do :
  done
  echo $rnd
}
```

**Wrapping things up**

Finally, we want to sample integers between `min` and `max`, where `min` and `max` can be arbitrary, even negative. As previously mentioned, this is now trivial.

Let's put it all in a bash script. Do some argument parsing stuff... We want two arguments `min` and `max`, or only one argument `max`, where `min` defaults to `0`.

```
# check number of parameters
if (( $# != 1 && $# != 2 ))
then
  cat <<EOF 1>&2
Usage: $(basename $0) [min] max

Returns an integer distributed uniformly at random in the range {min..max}
min defaults to 0
(max - min) can be up to 2**60-1  
EOF
  exit 1
fi

# If we have one parameter, set min to 0 and max to $1
# If we have two parameters, set min to $1 and max to $2
max=0
while (( $# > 0 ))
do
  min=$max
  max=$1
  shift
done

# ensure that min <= max
if (( min > max ))
then
  echo "$(basename $0): error: min is greater than max" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```

...and, finally, to sample uniformly at random a value between `min` and `max`, we sample a random integer between `0` and the absolute value of `max-min`, and add `min` to the final result. :-)

```
diff=$((max-min)) && diff=${diff#-}

echo $(( $(rand $diff) + min ))
```

Inspired by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525599/how-to-display-a-random-line-from-a-text-file/525624#comment721328_525624), I might try to use [dieharder](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dieharder.1.html) to test and benchmark this PRNG, and put my findings in here. :-)

Comment: your solution assumes that `sizeof(int) == 8` (64bit) due to `--format=u`

Comment: your solution reminds me how random.py is written. `random.Random` class uses 53bit? generator to return arbitrary large random numbers (multiple invocations), `random.SystemRandom` does the same using `os.urandom()` that can be implemented using `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: uL implies sizeof(long)>=8 for the range. It is not guaranteed. You could use u8 to assert that platform has such integer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I was thinking that so far my script does not hard-code any assumptions about the size of a long int. Potentially, it would work even if the size of a long signed int was greater (or lower) than 64 bits, e.g., 128 bits. However, if I use `--format=u8` then I hardcode the assumption `sizeof(int)==8`. On the other hand, if use `--format=uL` there's no problem: I don't think there is a platform that *has* 64-bit integers but still defines long ints as something lower. So basically I would argue `--format=uL` allows for more flexibility. What are your thoughts?

Comment: there is `long long` that can be 64bit while int=long=32bit on some platforms. You should not claim 0..2**60 range if you can't guarantee it on all platforms. On the other hand bash might not support this range itself on such platforms (I don't know, perhaps it uses maxint_t and then u8 is more correct if you want to assert the fixed range (`od` doesn't support specifying maxint if yours range is whatever bash's platform-dependent? range is). If the bash range depends on sizeof long then uL might be more appropriate).  Do you want the full range that bash supports on all OSes or a fixed range?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian No, I am not interested in some fixed range. I want the script to be able to produce random integers as large as whatever bash supports on a given platform. Currently, my script clearly supports this when using `$RANDOM` (which is the default anyway); and when using `od`, I *think* it should also work since I'm using `--format=uL`. I assume (but am not sure, that was actually my main question) that `uL` also corresponds to the largest integers bash supports on a given platform, both perhaps dependent on `LONG_MAX` in `/usr/include/limits.h`.

Comment: And about the claims, you're right of course: While my script doesn't make any assumptions about the maximum size of an int, my comments and explanations probably do. I took the comments less seriously than the code ;) I'll fix the post to reflect that when time allows.

Comment: if you want to support the full bash range then `uL` (`long`) might be too small if bash uses maxint_t (or `long long` if they are different). `long long` is not a typo.

Comment: [indeed, `uL` (long) is the *minimum* that bash must support, gnu bash uses `maxint_t` type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26121659/4279)  that is equal or larger than `long`. `od` should be extended to support `maxint_t`.

Comment: I ran some tests, and I discovered that you can increase the speed of your script 100s-fold, if you don't bother calculating logarithms and such, but instead, just generate one 60-bit random number straight-up. Like `((RND=((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM))`  Also, later in your script, you are doing some right-shifting of bits which serves no purpose whatsoever, because you'll be doing a modulo division anyway -- so get rid of that too.  (some tests [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268952/using-dev-random-dev-urandom-to-generate-random-data/617159#617159).)

Comment: @Pourko Thanks. I immediately believe your method is faster, but I think you missed an important point. In the introduction above, I stated "*Falco's answer describes the general idea how this could be done for arbitrary ranges (not only powers of two). (...) My script is basically a concrete implementation of Falco's answer.*" Your method is only able to compute random numbers in the range from 0 to a power of two (minus 1). The main reason for my script is to circumvent this very limitation. The right-shifting also serves that purpose, as is described in detail in the post.

Comment: @Malte Skoruppa: What do you possibly mean by "only power of two"?  I have the full range from zero to 1152921504606846976. What exactly limitation are you circumventing? You can't possibly be talking about arbitrary numbers, higher than what the machine bitness is.

Answer (score 20):

I see another interesting method from [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6988/random-unsigned-integer).

```
rand=$(openssl rand 4 | od -DAn)
```

[This](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6981/random-unsigned-integer) one also seems to be a good option. It reads 4 bytes from the random device and formats them as unsigned integer between `0` and `2^32-1`.

```
rand=$(od -N 4 -t uL -An /dev/urandom | tr -d " ")
```

Comment: you should [use `/dev/urandom` unless you know that you need `/dev/random`](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/); `/dev/random` blocks on Linux.

Comment: why are `od` commands different. Both just print 4-bytes unsigned integers: 1st -- from openssl, 2nd -- from `/dev/random`.

Comment: Ok, so basically generate 4 random bytes either using `openssl` or `/dev/{u,}random` and format the output using `od`. We could equally use `openssl rand 4 | od -t uL -An` or `od -N 4 -DAn /dev/urandom`. Two questions: (1) Wouldn't `-t uI` be enough for up to `2^32-1` (i.e., 4 bytes?); and (2) I cannot find any information on `-D`, but its effect seems to be the same as `-t uI`, is that correct?

Comment: @Ramesh I edited to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` - I see no reason to use `/dev/random`, and it can be really expensive/slow, or slow down other parts of the system. (Feel free do edit back and explain if it is really needed.)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel, I am just reading difference between `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random`. I was not aware of it until you guys pointed out in this answer. Please feel free to edit/point out in case if am wrong. I appreciate it :)

Comment: No worries, it's really surprising that this simple difference has so complicated effects. That's why I insisted to change the example to the right one - people learn from examples.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa: `I` stands for `sizeof(int)` that may be less than `4` in principle. btw, `od -DAn` fails for `(2**32-1)` but `od -N4 -tu4 -An` continues to work.

Comment: update 64 bit: In machines of 64 bit, L may represent 8 Bytes. In those machines (quite common now) a format of `od -N4 -tuL -An` and `od -N4 -tu8 -An` will produce the same output. Up to `2^64-1=18446744073709551615`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, you are are right, the `od` commands shouldn't be much different. The only difference should be that you can omit `-N4` with `openssl` because you get an EOF after 4 bytes. The `-D` option isn't POSIX and not documented on Linux - on BSD/Solaris it is an alias for `-t u4`.

Comment: @user79743 - why not just use `-N4 -tu4`? This should work on 32 Bit and 64 Bit machines the same. Or if you need such large integers do read 8 bytes and use `-N8 -tu8`.

Answer (score 8):

Can it be zsh?

```
zmodload zsh/mathfunc
max=1000
integer rnd='rand48() * max'
```

(for random numbers between 0 and 999)

You may want to use seed as well with `rand48(seed)`. See `man zshmodules` and  `man 3 erand48` for detailed description if interested.

Comment: I personally don't use zsh, but this is a great addition :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a number from **0** through **(2^n)-1** where **n mod 8 = 0** you can simply get **n / 8** bytes from `/dev/random`. For example, to get the decimal representation of a random `int` you could:

```
od --read-bytes=4 --address-radix=n --format=u4 /dev/random | awk '{print $1}'
```

If you want to take just **n** *bits* you can first take **ceiling(n / 8)** bytes and *right shift* to the amount you want. For example if you want 15 bits:

```
echo $(($(od --read-bytes=2 --address-radix=n --format=u4 /dev/random | awk '{print $1}') >> 1))
```

If you are absolutely sure that you *don't care about the quality of the randomness* and you want to guarantee a *minimal run time* you can use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`. Make sure you know what you are doing before using `/dev/urandom`!

Comment: Thank you. So, get `n` random bytes from `/dev/urandom` and format using `od`. Similar in spirit as [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157266). Both are equally good :) Though both have the disadvantage of having a fixed range of 0 through 2^(n*8)-1 bits, where n is the number of bytes. I would prefer a method for an *arbitrary* range, *up to* 2^32-1, but also anything lower. This creates the bias difficulty.

Comment: Edited to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` - I see no reason to use `/dev/random`, and it can be really expensive/slow, or slow down other parts of the system. (Feel free do edit back and explain if it is really needed.)

Comment: It should be the exact opposite: [use /dev/urandom unless *you know* that you need /dev/random](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157250/how-to-efficiently-generate-large-uniformly-distributed-random-integers-in-bas/157263#comment257486_157266). It is incorrect to assume that `/dev/urandom` results are so much worse than `/dev/random` that urandom is not usable in *most* cases. Once `/dev/urandom` is initialized (at the start of the system); its results are as good as `/dev/random` for almost all applications on Linux. On some systems random and urandom are the same.

Comment: `--format=u` should be replaced with `--format=u4` because `sizeof(int)` may be less than `4` in theory.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian [This paper](https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.extended.pdf) has a very interesting discussion around this subject. Their conclusion seems to be that both `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` are unsatisfactory, and that "Linux should add a secure RNG that blocks until it has collected adequate seed entropy and thereafter behaves like `urandom`."

Comment: @l0b0: I'm sure there are many issues with /dev/(u)random on different systems. It doesn't change the suggestion that you should use /dev/urandom by default

Comment: When unsure, I like to err on the side of caution. Especially if it's not known what the randomness is going to be used for.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ python -c 'import random as R; print(R.randint(-3, 5**1234))'
```

`python` is available on Redhat, Debian-based systems.

Comment: +1 Ah, along with the [perl solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157259) there just had to be the python solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't object to using external tools, this should fulfill your requirements:

```
rand=$(perl -e 'print int(rand(2**32-1))');
```

It's using perl's `rand` function which takes an upper limit as a parameter. You can set it to whatever you like. How close this is to true randomness in the abstract mathematical definition is beyond the scope of this site but it should be fine unless you need it for extremely sensitive encryption or the like. Perhaps even there but I won't venture an opinion.

Comment: this breaks for large numbers [e.g., 5**1234](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157321/1321)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes it does. I posted this since the OP specified `1^32-1` but you need to tweak it for larger numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the nearest (2^X)-1 equal or grater than your desired maximum and get the number of bits. Then just call /dev/random multiple times and append all the bits together until you have enough, truncating all bits which are too much.
If the resulting number is bigger than your max repeat. In the worst case you have a greater than 50% chance of getting a random number below your Maximum so (for this worst case) you will take two calls on average.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good idea in order to improve efficiency. [Ramesh's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157266) and [l0b0's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157263) both basically get random bits from `/dev/urandom`, but in both answers it's always a multiple of 8 bits. Truncating the bits which are too much for lower ranges before formatting to decimal with `od` is a good idea to improve efficiency, since the loop only has an expected number of 2 iterations, as you nicely explain. This, combined with either one of the mentioned answers, is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For generating 32 bit random integers, just do:

```
min=0
max=4294967295
rnd=$((SRANDOM % ( max - min + 1 ) + min))
echo "$rnd"
```

`$SRANDOM`

- is available in `bash` since version 5.1
- supports a range of 32 bit (unsigned, with values uniformly distributed between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup> - 1)
- is self seeding and doesn't need and can't be seeded externally

Answer (score 1):

For generating p.e. 32 bit or 63 bit random integers, just do:

```bash
min=0  # min
max=4294967295  # for 32 bit 4.294.967.295, for 63 bit 9223372036854775807
n=1    # count of numbers, dont use a higher count than 1

shuf -rn "$n" -i "$min-$max"
```

Supports a range of up to 63 bit (unsigned, with values uniformly distributed between 0 and 9223372036854775807

Remark:

Dont generate more than one number by one call, if you need uniformly distributed numbers. P.e. if you need uniformly distributed numbers, you have to call it 10 times.

Comment: `seq 0 18446744073709551615` is going to take a few years to run. You can do `shuf -rn "$n" -i "$min-$max"` (with max <= 9223372036854775807)

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas, whats the reason for this ?

Comment: For `seq 0 18446744073709551615` to take years? Well, that's outputting hundreds of hexabytes of data. Even at 100GB/s, that would take over a century to produce.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, i fixed it now. THX

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is interesting but quite long.

If you want arbitrarily large numbers, then you could join multiple random numbers in a helper:

```
# $1 - number of 'digits' of size base
function random_helper()
{
  base=32768
  random=0
  for((i=0; i<$1; ++i)); do
    let "random+=$RANDOM*($base**$i)"
  done
  echo $random
}
```

If the problem is bias, then just remove it.

```
# $1 - min value wanted
# $2 - max value wanted
function random()
{
  MAX=32767
  min=$1
  max=$(($2+1))
  size=$((max-min))
  bias_range=$((MAX/size))
  while
    random=$RANDOM
  [ $((random/size)) -eq $bias_range ]; do :; done
  echo $((random%size+min))
}
```

Joining these functions together

```
# $1 - min value wanted
# $2 - max value wanted
# $3 - number of 'digits' of size base
function random()
{
  base=32768
  MAX=$((base**$3-1))
  min=$1
  max=$(($2+1))
  size=$((max-min))
  bias_range=$((MAX/size))
  while
    random=$(random_helper)
  [ $((random/size)) -eq $bias_range ]; do :; done
  echo $((random%size+min))
}
```

Comment: What the maximum range of this solution ? 32  Bit ? 256 Bit ?