# Generate random password with special characters on Solaris

Tags: solaris, password, random

I am trying to generate a 10-character random password in Solaris servers. The examples give around the web are for Linux and mostly not working in Solaris.

Comment: mostly not working in solaris

Comment: “10 digits” contradicts “special character”. What is your exact requirement? Edit your question. Your question may or may not end up being a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245036/random-number-generation-in-solaris) depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks - the password should be 10 characters - Alpha + Numeric+ Special character

Comment: A list of commands you tried and any output / error messages you got (and what you expected instead) might help to understand your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can get cryptographic-quality random bytes from `/dev/urandom`. (This exists since Solaris 9. It also exists on Linux.) This includes unprintable characters, so you need to remove those. The following command extracts 10 random printable, non-space ASCII characters.

```
</dev/urandom tr -dc '!-~' | dd ibs=1 obs=1 count=10
```

I don't recommend using special characters in passwords. They don't make passwords more secure. What makes the security of a password is its entropy. A 10-character password has 10×log<sub>2</sub>(94) ≈ 65.5 bits of entropy. You can get the same amount of entropy from 9 arbitrary bytes and encode them as you wish, for example as hexadecimal.

```
</dev/urandom dd ibs=1 obs=1 count=9 | od -tx1 -An | tr -d ' '
```

Or as Base64, which is shorter.

```
</dev/urandom dd ibs=1 obs=1 count=9 | uuencode -m - | sed -n 2p
```

If there's some hard constraint that “passwords must contain at least one special character” (which is a questionable way to make passwords *selected by average humans* more secure, and it completely wrong for randomly generated passwords), then you can't simply use a random password, because there's a chance that it'll happen not to contain any character in a required class. If you reject passwords that don't meet the constraint, you're *reducing* the security of the password. Instead, make the password longer, e.g.

```
</dev/urandom dd ibs=1 obs=1 count=9 | uuencode -m - | sed '2!d; s/$/-Aa1/'
```

If you need the password to be memorable, that's a different problem. The best memorable passwords are [passphrases](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: can this stdd in and out be removed please
sol10 # dd if=/dev/urandom ibs=1 obs=1 count=9 | uuencode -m - | sed '2!d; s/$/-Aa1/'
9+0 records in
9+0 records out
A9xk0r4MvMCY-Aa1
sol10 #

Comment: Thanks Much , this will eliminate the dd command output.
`dd if=/dev/urandom ibs=1 obs=1 count=9 2>/dev/null | uuencode -m - | sed '2!d; s/$/-Aa1/'`

Comment: I know this is old, but can you explain the `!-~` part passed to `tr`? From the man page it seems like it's all characters except the value of ! to ~? From my testing seems like I can definitely get random sequences with `!` `-` and `~` in them.  So not sure what that is excluding.  Thank you!

Comment: @xbakesx I think you missed `-c`. `tr -dc CHARS` deletes (`-d`) the characters in the complement (`-c`) of the set CHARS, i.e. it keeps the characters in CHARS. `tr -dc '!-~'` excludes control characters, non-ASCII characters and spaces.

Comment: That is definitely what I did.  So it keeps any characters between code points 33 `!` and 126 `~`.  Clever girl.

Answer (score -1):

You have perl in Solaris, it helps:

```
perl -e 'print[0..9,a..z,A..Z]->[rand 62]for 1..10'
```

With special characters it will be:

```
perl -e 'print [0..9,a..z,A..Z,qw{- _ / & ?}]->[rand 67]for 0..10'
```

Comment: Thanks - but there is no special characters.

       sol10 # perl -e 'print[0..9,a..z,A..Z]->[rand 62]for 1..10'
        e9RKUJiss3
        sol10 # perl -e 'print[0..9,a..z,A..Z]->[rand 62]for 1..10'
        zLdxvTqlJT
        sol10 # perl -e 'print[0..9,a..z,A..Z]->[rand 62]for 1..10'
        AiaiDubgye
        sol10 # perl -e 'print[0..9,a..z,A..Z]->[rand 62]for 1..10'
        lJxiV2iDwY
        sol10 #

Comment: You may add special characters in such way: 
perl -e 'print [a..z,A..Z,0..9,qw{- _ / & ?}]->[rand 67]for 0..10'

Comment: No, Perl's `rand` is not suitable to generate a password. **This answer is insecure.**