# $(echo $RANDOM | cut -b 1-2) returns empty line in a shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have this script,

```
#!/bin/sh
guess=$(echo $RANDOM | cut -b 1-2)

read -p "Im thinking of a number, can you guess what it is? " number

case "$number" in
    "$guess") echo "\nCongratulation number guessed corectly!"
        exit 0
        ;;
    *) echo "\nIncorrect number guessed, try again? [yes or no]"
        read yesorno
        case "$yesorno" in
            "yes") sh guess.sh
                ;;
            "no") echo "\nHave a nice day!"
                exit 0
                ;;
            *) echo "Invalid input"
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
esac
```

The variable $guess was suppossed to return a 2 digit number, but returns null. Running the game with `sh guess.sh` and pressing return, returns congrats instead of the correct number being guessed. Where am I going wrong

Comment: `sh` != `bash`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random number generation in Solaris?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245036/random-number-generation-in-solaris)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `bash` instead of `sh`

```
guess=$(echo $RANDOM | cut -b 1-2)
             ^-----^ SC3028: In POSIX sh, RANDOM is undefined.
```

Comment: `read -p` is furthermore not guaranteed to work in non-bash scripts. You may also want to comment on the way they run the script recursively...

Comment: Running this with ./guess.sh(provided that declare #!/bin/bash) runs fine, however, sh guess.sh shows faulty result.

Comment: That because you overwrite the shell which execute the script

Comment: Okay, I'm upvoting both of the answers, Adding #!/bin/bash solved the issue, if ran with ./guess.sh.

Answer (score 2):

The `-b` flag in cut is for bytes, try the `-c` flag for characters instead.

I would also suggest changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Otherwise it will use the system default (on Ubuntu this is `dash`) using POSIX mode.