# Using /dev/random, /dev/urandom to generate random data

Tags: command-line, random

I'm looking for ways to use `/dev/random` (or `/dev/urandom`) from the command line.  In particular, I'd like to know how to use such a stream as `stdin` to write streams of random numbers to `stdout` (one number per line).

I'm interested in random numbers for all the numeric types that the machine's architecture supports natively.  E.g. for a 64-bit architecture, these would include 64-bit signed and unsigned integers, and 64-bit floating point numbers.  As far as ranges go, the maximal ranges for the various numeric types will do.

I know how to do all this with all-purpose interpreters like Perl, Python, etc., but I'd like to know how to do this with "simpler" tools from the shell.  (By "simpler" I mean "more likely to be available even in a very minimal Unix installation".)

Basically the problem reduces that of converting binary data to their string representations on the command line.  (E.g., this won't do: `printf '%f\n' $(head -c8 /dev/random)`.)

I'm looking for shell-agnostic answers.  Also, the difference between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` is not important for this question.  I expect that any procedure that works for one will work for the other, even when the semantics of the results may differ.

---

I adapted EightBitTony's answer to produce the functions `toints`, etc. shown below.

Example use:

```
% < /dev/urandom toprobs -n 5
0.237616281778928
0.85578479125532
0.0330049682019756
0.798812391655243
0.138499033902422
```

Remarks:

1. I'm using `hexdump` instead of `od` because it gave me an easier way to format the output the way I wanted it;
2. Annoyingly though, `hexdump` does not support 64-bit integers (wtf???);
3. The functions' interface needs work (e.g. they should accept `-n5` as well as `-n 5`), but given my pitiful shell programming skillz, this was the best I could put together quickly.  (Comments/improvements welcome, as always.)

The big surprise I got from this exercise was to discover how *hard* it is to program on the shell the *most elementary* numerical stuff (e.g. read a hexadecimal float, or get the maximum native float value)...

---

```
_tonums () {
  local FUNCTION_NAME=$1 BYTES=$2 CODE=$3
  shift 3

  local USAGE="Usage: $FUNCTION_NAME [-n <INTEGER>] [FILE...]"
  local -a PREFIX

  case $1 in
    ( -n ) if (( $# > 1 ))
           then
               PREFIX=( head -c $(( $2 * $BYTES )) )
               shift 2
           else
               echo $USAGE >&2
               return 1
           fi ;;
    ( -* ) echo $USAGE >&2
           return 1 ;;
    (  * ) PREFIX=( cat ) ;;
  esac

  local FORMAT=$( printf '"%%%s\\n"' $CODE )
  $PREFIX "$@" | hexdump -ve $FORMAT
}

toints () {
  _tonums toints 4 d "$@"
}

touints () {
  _tonums touints 4 u "$@"
}

tofloats () {
  _tonums tofloats 8 g "$@"
}

toprobs () {
  _tonums toprobs 4 u "$@" | perl -lpe '$_/=4294967295'
}
```

Comment: `tr -cs '[:digit:]' '[\n*]' </dev/urandom` should give you integer number only.

Comment: as far as I am aware, /dev/random do not generate random numbers per se, but add noise to the mathematical functions that give pseudo-random number for them to become less predictable. You might want to look at http://randomlib.sourceforge.net

Comment: Related: [How to efficiently generate large, uniformly distributed, random integers in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157250/1321)

Comment: Do you need crypto-quality randomness, or is e.g. seeding based on the time good enough?

Comment: @Gilles: the motivation for my question was more to find out about shell and Unix tools than about randomness; I just wanted to know what basic Unix tools existed for converting a stream of binary data into their string representation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `od` to get numbers out of `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`.

For example,

2 byte unsigned decimal integers,

```
$ od -vAn -N2 -tu2 < /dev/urandom
24352
```

1 byte signed decimal integer,

```
$ od -vAn -N1 -td1 < /dev/urandom
-78
```

4 byte unsigned decimal integers,

```
$ od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom
3394619386
```

`man od` for more information on `od`.

Answer (score 14):

Some shells (e.g. `bash(1)`) have a `$RANDOM` "variable" that gives random numbers.

Comment: Keep in mind, that's 15-bit.

Comment: $SRANDOM offer a 32 bit range

Answer (score 10):

It it much more efficient to work with the Bash built-ins than shell out to external commands like `od`. Here is for example how you can get a 60-bit random number:

```bsh
((RND=((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM))
```

That will give a random number in the range of 0 to 1,152,921,504,606,846,975.
You can scale that down with a modulo division to whatever range you want.

As a practical example, let's say, I want to read one random sector from my hard disk, to wake up the disk from a standby state. I can do this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DEV=/dev/sda  # Let's say that this is the device we want to spin up.

# Get the device geometry...
read -d- SIZE64 BS <<<$(blockdev --getsize64 --getbsz $DEV)
((SECTORS=SIZE64/BS)) # The total number of $BS-sized sectors on that device.

((RND=(RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM)) # Generate a 45-bit random number.
((SECT=RND%SECTORS)) # The random sector that we will now read...

dd if=$DEV of=/dev/null bs=$BS skip=$SECT count=1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Done.

(Note: In this example I decided that a 45-bit random integer would be more than sufficient, and also a tiny little bit faster than the 60-bit one.)

---

**Update**:

To give some quantitative backup for the above speed claim:

```bsh
~# time for i in {1..10000} ;do RND=$(od -An -N7 -tu8 /dev/urandom) ;done

real    0m45.647s
user    0m17.540s
sys     0m28.807s

~# time for i in {1..10000} ;do ((RND=((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM)) ;done

real    0m0.112s
user    0m0.105s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
perl -le '
  while (q(
    c char,  C unsigned char, s! short, S! unsigned short,
    i! int,  I! unsigned int, l! long,  L! unsigned long,
    f float, d double,) =~ /(\S+) (.*?),/gs) {
    $size = length(pack $1, 0);
    sysread STDIN, $data, $size;
    print "$2($size): " . unpack($1, $data);
  }' < /dev/urandom
```

Which on a 64 bit system would give you something like:

```
char(1): -98
unsigned char(1): 62
short(2): -12526
unsigned short(2): 399
int(4): 499066219
unsigned int(4): 2312134917
long(8): -4889591208978026255
unsigned long(8): 2080566823379835456
float(4): 55.4727554321289
double(8): 8.6395690272822e-05
```

Answer (score 2):

bash has since version 5.1 or 5.2 a `$SRANDOM` "variable" that gives 32 bit random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
# Output 1 random value between 1 and 100
shuf --random-source='/dev/urandom' -n 1 -i 1-100;
# 57
```

> By default these commands use an internal pseudo-random generator initialized by a small amount of entropy, but can be directed to use an external source with the `--random-source=file` option. An error is reported if file does not contain enough bytes. For example, the device file `/dev/urandom`...

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html

---

Some examples:

```bash
shuf --random-source='/dev/urandom' -n 100 -i 1-5 | perl -pe 's/\n/ /g;';
# 2 1 5 4 3

shuf --random-source='/dev/urandom' -n 1 -i 1-18446744073709551615;
# 3784824711059790616

shuf --random-source='/dev/urandom' -n 1 -i 1-18446744073709551616;
# shuf: invalid input range: ‘18446744073709551616’: Value too large for defined data type

shuf --random-source='/dev/urandom' -n 1 -i 0-18446744073709551615;
# shuf: invalid input range: ‘0-18446744073709551615’

shuf --random-source='/dev/urandom' -i 1-18446744073709551615;
# shuf: memory exhausted
```

It's worth to state the following:

```bash
shuf -i 2-0; echo $?;
# shuf: invalid input range: ‘2-0’
# 1

shuf -i 1-0; echo $?;
# 0
```

---

Related: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14846285 (*Careful, shuf is not cryptographically safe by default*...)