# How to configure RANDOM for getting the same 32 bit range of random numbers, like by using SRANDOM?

Tags: bash, shell, random

Environment:

- Debian
- Bash

**What is known:**

`RANDOM` gives a random number in a range of 15 bits by the following:

```
echo $RANDOM
```

`SRANDOM` gives a random number in a range of 32 bits by the following:

```
echo $SRANDOM
```

`RANDOM` can be configured to create random numbers in a 30-bit range by the following:

```
my_rnd=$(((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)))
echo "$my_rnd"
```

`RANDOM` can be configured to create random numbers in a 45-bit range by the following:

```
my_rnd=$(((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)<<15|RANDOM))
echo "$my_rnd"
```

How can I configure `RANDOM` to get the same 32-bit range of random numbers as I get when using `SRANDOM`?

Comment: In general, if you need anything other than the simplest random numbers, bash is not a good language to write this.  Moreover, POSIX only guarantees arithmetic in `signed long`, so you might get a signed 32-bit integer here and therefore a negative value.  Calling Ruby's `SecureRandom.rand` would be a better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just do:

```
(( my_rnd = (RANDOM << 17) | (RANDOM << 2) | (RANDOM & 3) ))
```

That is, take all 15 bits of a first RANDOM, shifted 17 bits, another 15 bits of another RANDOM, shifted 2 bits, and an extra 2 bits of a third RANDOM (the lower ones, you could also use `RANDOM >> 13` for the higher ones, which at least in older versions of `bash` were significantly more *random*).

Comment: Its sounds for me the quality of RANDOM on new and old systems can be verry differnt. Which solution can be a good choice for unknown systems, which can be verry or old r actual also ?

Comment: @Eddy763, the poor randomness in the low bits is something I remember from the 90s. I don't know exactly when it was fixed but it probably was over 10 years ago so you're probably fine nowadays. In any case, whilst (pseudo-)random, $RANDOM is not cryptographically safe in that it is predictable. So not OK to generate passwords for instance.

Comment: @Eddy763 The [Wikipedia page on LCGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) has a couple of notes about the weaknesses in the low bits, but they depend on the magic numbers of the LCG. Bash looks to use x * 16807 mod 2^31-1, and uses a 32-bit value but returns only 15 bits, so it doesn't have the most critical issues. (Which would come if the modulus was a power of two.) It looks like the same equation since 4.0. But no, not in the same ballpark as actual cryptographically strong RNGs.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas Can you add the solution for the follow "you could also use RANDOM >> 13" THX

Answer (score 6):

```
my_rnd=$(((RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)))
```

What this does is only to use `RANDOM` twice, for 15 bits each, with the first value moved by 15 bits to the left. So you get a binary number like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`, where the a's are bits representing the first value and the b's the ones representing the second.

Similarly, to get any number of bits, you could use either `RANDOM` or `SRANDOM` to generate at least that many bits, collected together with shift (`<<`) and *or* (`|`), and then mask the rest out with *and* (`&`). E.g. for 32 bits, you'd use a mask of `0xffffffff` :

```
echo "$(( ((RANDOM<<30) | (RANDOM<<15) | RANDOM) & 0xffffffff ))"
```

(`0xffffffff` is the maximum 32-bit binary value, 4294967295 in decimal. You could also use `((1 << 32) - 1)` to calculate it on the fly.)

---

Note that Bash's manual doesn't seem to make any promises about how non-predictable the values produced by `RANDOM` are, but for `SRANDOM` it says that:

> `SRANDOM`
> This  variable  expands  to a 32-bit pseudo-random number each time it is referenced. The random number generator is not linear on systems that support `/dev/urandom` or `arc4random`, so each returned number has no relationship to the numbers preceding it.

which implies that `RANDOM` could indeed be a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which is to say, not a very good random generator. `/dev/urandom` and `arc4random` are implemented with better algorithms, so if it's available, you should use `SRANDOM`.

---

Even if `SRANDOM` is not available in your version of Bash, chances are your system has `/dev/urandom` available. So, if you do need better random numbers than what `RANDOM` provides, you could use that directly. Building on an answer in [Using /dev/random, /dev/urandom to generate random data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268952/170373), this would fill the shell array `arr` with `n` random 32-bit numbers:

```
n=10
arr=( $(od -vAn -N $((n*4)) -tu4 < /dev/urandom) )
```

<sub>(using word splitting on purpose, `IFS` must not contain digits.)</sub>

Comment: In older versions of `bash`, `$RANDOM` (initially a ksh feature) randomness was notoriously very bad and hardly usable.