# edit repo file with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, repository

I want to edit manually my repo file from the command-line, preferably using `sed`. How can I do that based on the repo-name I want to edit?

I want to search for a specific repo-name (example: reponame-2) and based on that change, for example, the option `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`

```
[repo-name1]
name=repo-name1
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled=1
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_


[repo-name2]
name=repo-name2
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled=1
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_
```

Comment: Does it *need* to be sed? This is trivial in Perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl's "paragraph mode", where "lines" are defined by consecutive newlines, is perfect for this:

```
$ perl -00pe 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/ if /\[repo-name1/' file [repo-name1]
name=repo-name1
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled=0
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_


[repo-name2]
name=repo-name2
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled=1
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_
```

Or, to edit the original file directly:

```
perl -i -00pe 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/ if /\[repo-name1/' file
```

Alternatively, you could use `awk`:

```
$ awk -vRS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' '/\[repo-name1/{sub(/enabled=1/,"enabled=0")}1;' file 
[repo-name1]
name=repo-name1
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled=0
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_

[repo-name2]
name=repo-name2
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled=1
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_
```

And, if you have a recent version of GNU-awk or any other `awk` suporting `-i`, you can do this to edit in place:

```
awk -iinplace -vRS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' '/\[repo-name1/{sub(/enabled=1/,"enabled=0")}1;' file
```

Alternatively, to avoid the extra blank lines that the `awk` above adds to the end of the file, you could do something more complex like:

```
$ awk -F= '/\[repo-name1/{a=1}/^\s*$/{a=0}a==1 && $1=="enabled"{$2=0}1;' file
[repo-name1]
name=repo-name1
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled 0
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_

[repo-name2]
name=repo-name2
baseurl=http://linktomyrepo.com
enabled=1
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_
```

Comment: works very well. it would be nice if i could use sed or awk. because im not sure all my systems has perl installed by default.

Comment: @AsafMagen the vast majority of *nix systems will have Perl installed. Granted, [not all](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123149/22222), so I added ann `awk` solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
sed -i '/repo-name1/{n;n;n;s/enabled=1/enabled=0/}' repos.txt
```

This requires that `enabled=` always be at the third line after repo name.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` one can set record separator to double newlines to in some way simulate `perl`'s paragraph mode as in [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289966/80886):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";OFS="\n"} \
     /repo-name1/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="enabled=1") $i="enabled=0"}1' file
```

Comment: You might also want to set `ORS` so that the blank lines are kept in the output.

Comment: @terdon yes, I see that you added your `awk` solution with this, but one will end up with blank lines also at the end of the file. `awk` is not best for this job, perl is better.

Comment: Never mind, I added another approach that avoids the newlines.